# macOS bitbucket not able pull and push throwing error

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I recently change to bitbucket, I have 3 repos, which is written in `go lang` and dependent each other. I am able to clone the projects, but whenever I am trying to build project, some dependency attached different repo, due this, bitbucket gives me error as below. I have created app password in bitbucket, but still its same error. Before whenever `go` was trying to pull package `vscode` used to prompt the password, after-while its not working. I am not sure what I am missing here.

`go version go1.20.2 darwin/arm64`

`macOS : venture 13.2.1`

`chip : Apple M2 Pro`

> fatal: could not read Username for 'https://bitbucket.org': terminal prompts disabled
> Confirm the import path was entered correctly.
> If this is a private repository, see https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https for additional information.

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://username@bitbucket.org/app/myrepo1.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "main"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/main
```

```
module myrepo1

go 1.19

require (
    bitbucket.org/apps/myrepo2
    bitbucket.org/apps/myrep3 
)
```